# Ошибка в коде, не подставляется цифра из переменной в запрос

Tags: php, mysql

Добрый день, друзья. Прошу помочь. Написал такой код:

```
$qurum = explode('|', $qurum1);//1|2|6
  foreach ($qurum as $value) {
  $idareid = 'idare'.$value;
  if (table_exists($idareid)) {
    $sql = "SELECT qurum1 FROM data WHERE id = $id";//1|2|3
    $res = mysql_query($query);
    $get_qur = array();
    $get_qur = mysql_fetch_assoc($res);
    $get_q = explode('|', $get_qur['qurum1']);//1|2|3
      foreach ($get_q as $v) {
        if (in_array($v, $qurum)) {
          $mysql = "UPDATE ".$idareid." SET data_num = '$data_num',
          input_date = '$input_date' WHERE data_id = $id";
          $result = mysql_query($mysql) or die("O ".mysql_error());
        } else {
          $query = "DELETE FROM idare".$v." WHERE data_id = $id";
          $r = mysql_query($query) or die("w ".mysql_error());
          $mysql2 = "INSERT INTO ".$idareid." (data_id, data_num, input_date) VALUES
                    ('$id', '$data_num', '$input_date')";
          $result2 = mysql_query($mysql2) or die("i ".mysql_error());
                    }
                }
        } else {
            $q = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ".$idareid." ( " . $idareid . "_id tinyint(4) 
UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, `data_id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL, `data_num` 
varchar(255) NOT NULL, `input_date` date NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY(" . $idareid ."_id))
ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1";
            $res2 = mysql_query($q) or die("b ".mysql_error());
            $query2 = "INSERT INTO ".$idareid." (data_id, data_num, input_date) VALUES
             ('$id', '$data_num', '$input_date')";
        $res3 = mysql_query($query2) or die("k".mysql_error());
        }

    }
```

**У меня 2 вопроса:**

1. Выдает ошибку:

   > w Table 'project.idare' doesn't exist

   Тут по идее должна быть цифра 3 т.е. должно получиться `idare3` и таблица `idare3` существует.
2. Можно ли как то упростить этот код?

Благодарю за помощь!

Comment: @Arnial да я уверен.

Comment: $get_qur это то что в базе, а $qurum - измененная (присланная из) в форме

Comment: В таком случае она либо начиниется с "|" либо пустая. В клюбом случае ошибка в первых трех строчках. Иначе скрипт упалбы на `$get_q = explode('|', $get_qur)` т.к. `explode` не может  принимать массив вторым параметром (а false может). А значит первый селект вернул пустой набор, и в запросе находится не то что вы ожидали.

Comment: Вы правы var_dump($get_q); array(1) { [0]=> string(0) "" }

Comment: Вместо $res = mysql_query($query); надо было $res = mysql_query($sql); но теперь var_dump($get_q) дает NULL почему то

Comment: сделайте `var_dump( $get_qur )`;

Comment: @JabbarGuliyev Выполняя `$get_qur = mysql_fetch_assoc($res);` вы помещаете в `$get_qur` - **массив** (или `bool`, но никак не `string`). Применять `explode` к массиву (как и к логическому значению) бесполезно.

Comment: var_dump($get_qur) возвращает вот это - array(1) { ["qurum1"]=> string(7) "1|2|3|6" }

Comment: $get_q = explode('|', $get_qur); надо было дописать ['qurum1']

Comment: Проблема пропала?

Comment: @DmitriySimushev да Слава Богу и спасибо Вам за помощь

Answer (score 1):

1. Забудьте уже о расширении mysql, оно объявлено устаревшим еще в PHP 5.5, а в 7.0 так вообще удалено. Используйте [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/ru/book.mysqli.php) либо [PDO](http://php.net/manual/ru/pdo.connections.php)
2. Вставьте отладку для своих переменных, чтобы быть уверенным, что в них содержится именно то, что вам нужно. [var_dump](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.var-dump.php) вам в помощь
3. Старайтесь избегать подстановки переменных непосредственно в SQL-запрос. Используйте [подготовленные запросы](http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.prepare.php) и [связывание переменных](http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php)
4. Зачем вам тут `foreach ($get_q as $k => $v) {` получать ключ, если вы его нигде не используете?

Comment: if (in_array($v, $qurum))  и чуть ниже использую

Comment: @JabbarGuliyev `$v` - это значение, я про `$k`

Comment: Сорри, вы правы. щас исправлю тут